Django merge two m2m_change signals
i have a post model which has category m2m field and tag m2m field, on post post_save i want to retrieve the category ids and tag ids from that post model instance, but after some research i found out, m2m fields arnt save at that time and i want to use m2m_changed signal, but since i have two m2m fields, how can i merge two signals or in posts post_save is there a way to wait for the creation of m2m fields, or do i have to create custom signal
class Category(models.Model):
    description = RichTextField(null=True, max_length=10000)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
    # readonly fields
    wp_category_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, editable=False)
    total_posts = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, editable=False)
    category_link = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

class Tags(models.Model):
    description = RichTextField(null=True, max_length=10000)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    
    # readonly fields
    wp_tag_id = models.CharField(null=False, editable=False, max_length=10)
    tag_link = models.CharField(null=True, editable=False, max_length=400)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"

class Posts(models.Model):
    wp_post_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, editable=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=status_choices, max_length=200)
    ....
    sticky = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="categories", blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True, related_name="tags")
    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.title}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"


